# Appending values to a vector from replicate function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to replicate a function some number of times, and at the end of each iteration append a value to a vector so that by the end of the replication I'll have a vector with entries that I can take the mean of.

This is my code

```
z <- vector()
n <- 1000

maxrep <- replicate(3, {
print(paste0("z0: ", z))
stop <- FALSE
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0.001,1000), ylim=c(0.001,4), ylab="unif value", xlab="n=1000")
y <- runif(1000, 0, theta)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  thetamax <- max(y[1:i])
  points(i, thetamax)
  if (thetamax >= 2.9 & stop == FALSE) {
    #print(paste0(i, ": ", thetamax))
    num <- i
    stop <- TRUE
  }
}
z <- append(z, num)
print(paste0("z1: ", z))
})
```

I want to append to z, but every time that the replicate function repeats itself, for some reason z becomes an empty vector again, and the value added disappears. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: End your anonymous function with `return(num)` to actually return the value. Then `maxrep` will contain the three values of `num` that you are looking for.

Comment: Also, you may want to consider what happens when 1000 iterations are not enough. What is supposed to happen if `num` is never created (i.e. `thetamax >= 2.9` is never true)?

Comment: I added return(num) to the end of my replicate function and tried testing if it stored the value with print(num) after. Nothing is disiplayed. If I put return into my if statement or for loop it comes with error messages.  This is where I put my return(num)

Comment: z <- vector()
n <- 1000

maxrep <- replicate(3, {
  print(paste0("z0: ", z))
  stop <- FALSE
  plot(NULL, xlim=c(0.001,1000), ylim=c(0.001,4), ylab="unif value", xlab="n=1000")
  y <- runif(1000, 0, theta)
  for (i in 1:1000) {
    thetamax <- max(y[1:i])
    points(i, thetamax)
    if (thetamax >= 2.9 & stop == FALSE) {
      #print(paste0(i, ": ", thetamax))
      num <- i
      stop <- TRUE
    }
  }
return(num)
print(num)
})

Answer (score 0):

As I said, it is `maxrep` that contains the values, not `num`. The variable `num` only exists within the call the `replicate`, and not in the global environment.

Here is a working version of your code (I've removed the plotting and printing for clarity):

```
n <- 1000
theta <- 3 # you didn't define this, so I'm guessing

maxrep <- replicate(3, {
  Stop <- FALSE
  y <- runif(n, 0, theta)
  
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    thetamax <- max(y[1:i])
    if (thetamax >= 2.9 & !Stop) {
      num <- i
      Stop <- TRUE
    }
  }
  # what if the stop condition was never satisfied? What should num be? n?
  if (!Stop) num <- n
  
  return(num)
})

maxrep
```

`maxrep` will contain the values, e.g. `[1] 11 27 60`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting this for me. I really appreciate it!